# Linq GroupBy. Return top one item of a subset of data

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by

I have a table of flight price data and I want to return the top 1 cheapest flight to each destination destination.  The table has the following basic fields:

```
FlightInfoID
AirportFrom
AirportTo
Price
```

I tried the following but it did not return the results I expected as there were multiple items for a specific destination and I only want 1 result per destination so if I have 50 destinations I would get 50 items returned.

```
lstBestFlightDealsForAllRoutes.OrderBy(p=> p.Price).GroupBy(x => x.AirportTo).First();
```

Comment: switch the groupby and orderby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from f in lstBestFlightDealsForAllRoutes
group f by new { f.AirportFrom, f.AirportTo } into g // group by route
select g.OrderBy(x => x.Price).First() // select cheapest flight
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Group flights by destination
2. From each group select the cheapest flight in the group

Lniq makes 2 difficult (the Minimum function is useless), but you can do it (with a small performance cost) by ordering each group by price and selecting the first from each group, eg.

```
flights.GroupBy(f => f.Destination).Select(g => g.OrderBy(f => f.Cost)).Select(g => g.First())
```